# How to share a variable between routing-functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a serverside parser of an API. Every get-request to my site needs to start with a request to that api, the request to the api is always the same, so I want to put it in it's own function.

How can I pass the response-variable from the api-function to the render-function?

```
var api = function (req, res, next) {
  http.get({...}), function(response){}
  next();
}

var render = function (req, res, next) {
  app.res.render('master',response);
  next();
}

app.get('/example/d', [api, render]);
```

Comment: your terminology is confusing - an HTTP "request" is a standalone transaction

Comment: @Alnitak It's a sort of middleware function, if I'm reading it correctly

Comment: @aw04 yes, that's what I figured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it to `req` before calling `next()`.

```
req.response = response;
```

And in your next...

```
var response = req.response;
```